# How to fix "sdk required for building..." on reactnative project to start my mobile peroject with react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

when I run react-native doctor, give me this:

```
✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly      
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android 
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android    
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 33.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

Errors:   1
```

[image]

I've already done the entire process described on the official React Native website in the setup part, but I always have this problem.